# Inproc speech recognition engine in Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm currently using PySpeech to recognize speech. I'm trying to get voice recognition to start without Windows Speech Recognition's default commands.

From googling, I've found that changing this line in speech.py from:

`_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpSharedRecognizer")`

to:

`_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpInprocRecognizer")`

doesn't include all the default commands. When I test whether or not the recognizer is listening, it returns false. At this point I'm just trying to get pySpeech to recognize what I'm saying and say it back to me.

#### Test Code:

```
import speech

speech.say("say something") #<--- says "say something"
print speech.input() #<--- gets stuck here
print speech.islistening() #<----- prints False
```

#### speech.py:

```
"""
speech recognition and voice synthesis module.

Please let me know if you like or use this module -- it would make my day!

speech.py: Copyright 2008 Michael Gundlach  (gundlach at gmail)
License: Apache 2.0 (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

For this module to work, you'll need pywin32 (http://tinyurl.com/5ezco9
for Python 2.5 or http://tinyurl.com/5uzpox for Python 2.4) and
the Microsoft Speech kit (http://tinyurl.com/zflb).


Classes:
    Listener: represents a command to execute when phrases are heard.

Functions:
    say(phrase): Say the given phrase out loud.
    input(prompt, phraselist): Block until input heard, then return text.
    stoplistening(): Like calling stoplistening() on all Listeners.
    islistening(): True if any Listener is listening.
    listenforanything(callback): Run a callback when any text is heard.
    listenfor(phraselist, callback): Run a callback when certain text is heard.


Very simple usage example:

import speech

speech.say("Say something.")

print "You said " + speech.input()

def L1callback(phrase, listener):
    print phrase

def L2callback(phrase, listener):
    if phrase == "wow":
        listener.stoplistening()
    speech.say(phrase)

# callbacks are executed on a separate events thread.
L1 = speech.listenfor(["hello", "good bye"], L1callback)
L2 = speech.listenforanything(L2callback)

assert speech.islistening()
assert L2.islistening()

L1.stoplistening()
assert not L1.islistening()

speech.stoplistening()
"""

from win32com.client import constants as _constants
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import time
import thread

# Make sure that we've got our COM wrappers generated.
from win32com.client import gencache
gencache.EnsureModule('{C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628}', 0, 5, 0)

_voice = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpInprocRecognizer")
_listeners = []
_handlerqueue = []
_eventthread=None

class Listener(object):

    """Listens for speech and calls a callback on a separate thread."""

    _all = set()

    def __init__(self, context, grammar, callback):
        """
        This should never be called directly; use speech.listenfor()
        and speech.listenforanything() to create Listener objects.
        """
        self._grammar = grammar
        Listener._all.add(self)

        # Tell event thread to create an event handler to call our callback
        # upon hearing speech events
        _handlerqueue.append((context, self, callback))
        _ensure_event_thread()

    def islistening(self):
        """True if this Listener is listening for speech."""
        return self in Listener._all

    def stoplistening(self):
        """Stop listening for speech.  Returns True if we were listening."""

        try:
            Listener._all.remove(self)
        except KeyError:
            return False

        # This removes all refs to _grammar so the event handler can die
        self._grammar = None

        if not Listener._all:
            global _eventthread
            _eventthread = None # Stop the eventthread if it exists

        return True

_ListenerBase = win32com.client.getevents("SAPI.SpSharedRecoContext")
class _ListenerCallback(_ListenerBase):

    """Created to fire events upon speech recognition.  Instances of this
    class automatically die when their listener loses a reference to
    its grammar.  TODO: we may need to call self.close() to release the
    COM object, and we should probably make goaway() a method of self
    instead of letting people do it for us.
    """

    def __init__(self, oobj, listener, callback):
        _ListenerBase.__init__(self, oobj)
        self._listener = listener
        self._callback = callback

    def OnRecognition(self, _1, _2, _3, Result):
        # When our listener stops listening, it's supposed to kill this
        # object.  But COM can be funky, and we may have to call close()
        # before the object will die.
        if self._listener and not self._listener.islistening():
            self.close()
            self._listener = None

        if self._callback and self._listener:
            newResult = win32com.client.Dispatch(Result)
            phrase = newResult.PhraseInfo.GetText()
            self._callback(phrase, self._listener)

def say(phrase):
    """Say the given phrase out loud."""
    _voice.Speak(phrase)


def input(prompt=None, phraselist=None):
    """
    Print the prompt if it is not None, then listen for a string in phraselist
    (or anything, if phraselist is None.)  Returns the string response that is
    heard.  Note that this will block the thread until a response is heard or
    Ctrl-C is pressed.
    """
    def response(phrase, listener):
        if not hasattr(listener, '_phrase'):
            listener._phrase = phrase # so outside caller can find it
        listener.stoplistening()

    if prompt:
        print prompt

    if phraselist:
        listener = listenfor(phraselist, response)
    else:
        listener = listenforanything(response)

    while listener.islistening():
        time.sleep(.1)

    return listener._phrase # hacky way to pass back a response...

def stoplistening():
    """
    Cause all Listeners to stop listening.  Returns True if at least one
    Listener was listening.
    """
    listeners = set(Listener._all) # clone so stoplistening can pop()
    returns = [l.stoplistening() for l in listeners]
    return any(returns) # was at least one listening?

def islistening():
    """True if any Listeners are listening."""
    return not not Listener._all

def listenforanything(callback):
    """
    When anything resembling English is heard, callback(spoken_text, listener)
    is executed.  Returns a Listener object.

    The first argument to callback will be the string of text heard.
    The second argument will be the same listener object returned by
    listenforanything().

    Execution takes place on a single thread shared by all listener callbacks.
    """
    return _startlistening(None, callback)

def listenfor(phraselist, callback):
    """
    If any of the phrases in the given list are heard,
    callback(spoken_text, listener) is executed.  Returns a Listener object.

    The first argument to callback will be the string of text heard.
    The second argument will be the same listener object returned by
    listenfor().

    Execution takes place on a single thread shared by all listener callbacks.
    """
    return _startlistening(phraselist, callback)

def _startlistening(phraselist, callback):
    """
    Starts listening in Command-and-Control mode if phraselist is
    not None, or dictation mode if phraselist is None.  When a phrase is
    heard, callback(phrase_text, listener) is executed.  Returns a
    Listener object.

    The first argument to callback will be the string of text heard.
    The second argument will be the same listener object returned by
    listenfor().

    Execution takes place on a single thread shared by all listener callbacks.
    """
    # Make a command-and-control grammar        
    context = _recognizer.CreateRecoContext()
    grammar = context.CreateGrammar()

    if phraselist:
        grammar.DictationSetState(0)
        # dunno why we pass the constants that we do here
        rule = grammar.Rules.Add("rule",
                _constants.SRATopLevel + _constants.SRADynamic, 0)
        rule.Clear()

        for phrase in phraselist:
            rule.InitialState.AddWordTransition(None, phrase)

        # not sure if this is needed - was here before but dupe is below
        grammar.Rules.Commit()

        # Commit the changes to the grammar
        grammar.CmdSetRuleState("rule", 1) # active
        grammar.Rules.Commit()
    else:
        grammar.DictationSetState(1)

    return Listener(context, grammar, callback)

def _ensure_event_thread():
    """
    Make sure the eventthread is running, which checks the handlerqueue
    for new eventhandlers to create, and runs the message pump.
    """
    global _eventthread
    if not _eventthread:
        def loop():
            while _eventthread:
                pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
                if _handlerqueue:
                    (context,listener,callback) = _handlerqueue.pop()
                    # Just creating a _ListenerCallback object makes events
                    # fire till listener loses reference to its grammar object
                    _ListenerCallback(context, listener, callback)
                time.sleep(.5)
        _eventthread = 1 # so loop doesn't terminate immediately
        _eventthread = thread.start_new_thread(loop, ())
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, as I mentioned, in-process recognizers don't have default input sources or recognition engines set up.  In order to get the in-process recognizer to listen, you need to set these via `_recognizer.SetInput` ([to set the input source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and `_recognizer.SetRecognizer` ([to set the recognition engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

The challenge for you is to get the default input source and recognition engine, respectively.  If you were using C++, this would be straightforward; there's a helper function in sphelper.h that gets the default input source: `SpGetDefaultTokenFromCategoryId(SPCAT_AUDIOIN, &cpToken)`, and I published a function [on my blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2010/03/01/specifying-parameters-for-an-inproc-recognizer.aspx) that gets the default recognition engine.

But I don't know how to translate those functions into Python; perhaps you do.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following [post](http://www.renuncln.com/blog/2012/05/29/python-speech-recognition-and-tts-part-ii-pyspeech/) when I faced the same problem.

Basically, you have to modify some lines on speech.py:

1. Change the line `_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpSharedRecognizer")` into `_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpInProcRecognizer")`
2. Add this line after the previous line: `_recognizer.AudioInputStream = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpMMAudioIn")`
3. Change the line `_ListenerBase = win32com.client.getevents("SAPI.SpSharedRecoContext")` into `_ListenerBase = win32com.client.getevents("SAPI.SpInProcRecoContext")`

Answer (score 1):

This question is really old but here's a module based on PySpeech (Python 2) that supports both InProcRecognizers and SharedRecognizer: [winspeech](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/winspeech). Works for both Python 2 and 3.